If two families over $\mathbb{P}^1$ are fiberwise birational, then the two families are birational
Let $f_1:X_1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ and $f_2:X_2 \to \mathbb {P}^1$ be two smooth projective morphisms over $\mathbb{P}^1$. Assume $X_1$ and $X_2$ are smooth varieties. Let $g:X_1\to X_2$ be a morphism between these two families (so that $f_2 \circ g = f_1$).
If the morphism $g:X_1 \to X_2$ induces fiberwise birational morphism (that is $g_s = g|_{(X_1)_s}:(X_1)_s \to (X_2)_s$ is birational) and furthermore separates the fibers (that is $g_s \ne g_t$ if $t \ne s $, where we treat the image in the ambient projective space of $X_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, and this condition means the image are distinct in that projective space), can we show that $g$ is actually a birational morphism?


What does your condition $g_s \ne g_t$ mean? In what sense maps between different varieties could be equal?

Dear @Sasha , Perhaps I should make it more clear, I should assume that the fibers are projective varieties in a fixed projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, and seperate them means that image in this fixed projective space are not the same. (The source of this question coming from the classical paper "Higher Direct Images of Dualizing Sheaves I" by Professor Kollár Theorem 4.6.)

Sorry, maybe my question is not precise enough, since I want to extract some certain points from that paper.
